# [Ignition] PostRender event not called

Tags: ros-noetic, ignition-fortress, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I have a problem when integrating a camera plugin that I designed in ROS.
If I use the plugin in a world created with an SDF it correctly works, but if I attach it to a camera declared in a URDF to be used in ROS, the `PostRender` event (`ignition::gazebo::events::PostRender`) is never called and I cannot understand why.
The plugin is correctly loaded, the `Configure` and `PostUpdate` callbacks are correctly called.

Any idea?

Thank you
Walter

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28370/%5Bignition%5D-postrender-event-not-called/) by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem was the missing MinimalScene plugin.
When I added it and correctly set all the environment paths everything started to work as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Myzhar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87579/myzhar/) with karma: 5 on 2022-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0